# SELECT query based on CODE column as its datatype is VARCHAR2 - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have 3 tables.

TABLE1 with one column ROLL_NO

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (ROLL_NO NUMBER(3) NOT NULL);
```

TABLE2 with 3 columns ROLL_NO, CLASS, SEC

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE2 (ROLL_NO NUMBER(3) NOT NULL, CLASS NUMBER(3) NOT NULL, SEC NUMBER(3) NOT NULL);
```

TABLE3 with 3 columns ROLL_NO, CODE, AMT

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE3 (ROLL_NO NUMBER(3) NOT NULL, CODE VARCHAR2(3) NOT NULL, AMT NUMBER(3) NOT NULL);


 INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (101);
 INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (102);
 INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (103);
 INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (104);
 ----------------------------------
 INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES (101,1, 12);
 INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES (102,1, 15);
 INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES (103,1, 25);
 INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES (104,1, 34);
 --------------------------------------
 INSERT INTO TABLE3 VALUES (101, 'A2', 100);
 INSERT INTO TABLE3 VALUES (101, '10', 200);
 INSERT INTO TABLE3 VALUES (102, 'B3', 300);
 INSERT INTO TABLE3 VALUES (102, '10', 400);
 INSERT INTO TABLE3 VALUES (102, '19', 500);
 INSERT INTO TABLE3 VALUES (103, '04', 600);
 INSERT INTO TABLE3 VALUES (103, '98', 700);
```

The SQL query which mentioned below:

```
SELECT T1.ROLL_NO, 
  T2.CLASS, 
  T2.SEC, 
  NVL(T3.CODE,0) AS CODE, 
  NVL(T3.AMT, 0) AS AMT
 FROM TABLE1 T1
 JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.ROLL_NO = T2.ROLL_NO
 LEFT JOIN TABLE3 T3 ON T1.ROLL_NO = T3.ROLL_NO
 WHERE T1.ROLL_NO IN (101,102,103,104);
```

If we don't find any record i.e. CODE and AMT for particular ROLL_NO, by default we are assigning as 0.

The result for above query:

```
ROLL_NO   CLASS   SEC    CODE    AMT
-------------------------------------
 101       1      12     A2      100
 101       1      12     10      100
 102       1      15     B3      300
 102       1      15     10      400
 102       1      15     19      500
 103       1      25     04      600
 103       1      25     98      700
 104       1      34      0        0
```

I am looking for a query in such a way that

```
a) if particular ROLL_NO has CODE value 10 and also additional CODE values other than 10 (might be A2, B3, 01 so on) then get that row which has CODE value as 10 in the result table.

b) if particular ROLL_NO don't have CODE 10 but has other additional CODE values then get that row in the result table.
```

In previous table, ROLL_NO 101 and 102 comes under case 'a' and 103, 104 comes under case 'b'

Final result should be

```
  ROLL_NO   CLASS   SEC    CODE    AMT
 -------------------------------------
   101       1      12     10      200
   102       1      15     10      400
   103       1      25     04      600
   103       1      25     98      700
   104       1      34      0        0
```

I am looking for a query to get the above result but I am not able to get it. I think RANK functions can't be used because CODE column datatype is VARCHAR2 and can't select based on sorting the CODE column value

Comment: Can you express the logic to get the AMT. I couldn't understand how they return for roll_no 101 and 102 ...

Answer (score 4):

If you want to give preference to code value 10 over everything else, You have to use a case statement with ROW_NUMBER() function.

```
SELECT T1.ROLL_NO, 
      T2.CLASS, 
      T2.SEC, 
      NVL(TO_NUMBER(T3.CODE),0) AS CODE, 
      NVL(T3.AMT, 0) AS AMT
FROM TABLE1 T1
JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.ROLL_NO = T2.ROLL_NO
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ROLL_NO, CODE, AMT,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ROLL_NO ORDER BY CASE CODE WHEN '10' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC) RN
             FROM TABLE3) T3 ON T1.ROLL_NO = T3.ROLL_NO
                            AND RN = 1
WHERE T1.ROLL_NO IN (101,102,103,104);
```

Also, I have used TO_NUMBER function with code column to show all the values as number else 4 will be shown up as '04'.

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=63c81f6b3ac2556628e87d2d344da216)

Comment: 4 is not same as '04' right? 4 is a number and '04' is a VARCHAR

Comment: Yes. If it doesn't matter to show 4 as 04, You can remove that TO_NUMBER function.